# sqoop incremental import updated row and newly created record

Tags: mysql, hive, sqoop, sqoop2

I have the sqoop job created with incremental append with last value

Job:

```
sqoop job --create myjob2 -- import --connect jdbc:mysql://host/DBnam -username user -password passwor --table savingssmal --check-column id --incremental append --last-value 0 --target-dir /user/xxxx/prac/sqoop --split-by id --as-parquetfile -m 1
```

My question is: I want to import the newly created record and also updated record into a mysql table?

Can you please help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `lastmodified` mode for incremental Sqoop import.

The `append` mode (used in your example) is used to import rows based on increasing row id values. So, when the job runs, it will import rows where `--check-column` (i.e. `id`) is greater than `--last-value` (i.e. `0`). If a row is updated, the `id` will generally remain the same and the updated row won't be imported.

The `lastmodified` mode is used to import rows based on a timestamp column (for example, `last_modified_time`). When the job runs, it will import rows where `--check-column` is more recent than specified via `--last-value`. The application writing to the table should update the `last_modified_time` column on inserts and updates. This way, both newly inserted and updated rows will be imported when the Sqoop job runs.

A sample invocation based on your example with the `lastmodified` mode would be as below:

```
sqoop job --create myjob2 -- import --connect jdbc:mysql://host/DBnam -username user -password passwor --table savingssmal --check-column last_update_time --incremental lastmodified --last-value "2018-02-03 04:38:39.0" --target-dir /user/xxxx/prac/sqoop --as-parquetfile -m 1
```